# Singleton retrofit

Tags: java, android

Как создать один класс на весь проект и использовать его во всех Presenter`ах.

Answer (score 1):

Создать его в классе, унаследованном от `Application`, а лучше всего заюзать [dagger2](https://github.com/google/dagger). Справедливости ради нужно упомянуть о [Singlton](https://habrahabr.ru/post/27108/), именно этот способ рекомендует Dianne Hackborn (Software Engineer, Android Framework), но [мнения расходятся](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android).

Comment: Я бы хотел рассмотреть использование с Singlton, можете привести пример?

А еще лучше примеры. Реализацию в классе от Application и при Singlton

Comment: @АнтонМартынов, хорошая статья по теме http://ru-code-android.livejournal.com/4594.html